# Getting strings in a entry widget and printing some response through a label

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-3.4

So i saw many videos and questions and stuff but i'm still stuck on how i can respond to strings in an entry widget.so far all the tuts and videos seem to show how to handle numbers and not string,To be more specific i want to make a Tkinter Gui box that has an entry widget and when i type 'hey',it should respond/answer "hey" in/through a label,now the answering part is the one i know,i just don't know how to manipulate strings and not numbers in entry widgets.
Thanks,sorry for being a noob

Comment: why don't you post your code (or the relevant part of your code)?

Comment: i cant,i just dont know how my code is working ,having a hard time figuring out.can you tell me how to just make a response to a input string (like an easy explanation) sorry for being a noob

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `StringVar` to get/set the string value of an Entry widget:

```
import tkinter as tk
master = tk.Tk()

val = tk.StringVar()

entry = tk.Entry(master, textvariable=val)
entry.pack()

val.set("some value")
the_string = val.get()
print(the_string)
# some value
```